# How do I go about this unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I don't know how to write a unit test for some code I have. I understand what's going on in the code, but I'm not sure how to go about writing a unit test for it.

I have tried, but I am stumped at the moment. The code simply prints out an array of first names and strips out the special characters. I want to test the first line of the code and test if the special characters are stripped.

```
firstNameParts = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(first.split("( |-)")));
System.out.println("Length of First Name Parts: " + firstNameParts.size());
for (int i = 0; i < firstNameParts.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("First Name Part " + i + ":" + firstNameParts.get(i));
    // strip out special chars
    firstNameParts.set(i,firstNameParts.get(i).replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", ""));
    System.out.println("Stripped First Name Part " + i + ":" + firstNameParts.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Extract the first part, that you want to test, to a method that returns a List<String>, and test that method.

Comment: "test the first line of the code and test if the special characters are stripped": that's not what the first line does. It just splits the string into parts delimited by space or hyphen.

Comment: @Henry the string is split in the bottom half of the code.The first line does what u said.I explained it wrong.Id just like to know how it would be tested as a unit test.for those two steps.I cant wrap my head around it.

Comment: I think your confusion stems from wanting to test `System.out.println`, but you can't (or shouldn't try to) test that. You need to do something like what Bohemian suggests and change your code so you can test the complicated parts. People face a similar problem when they want to "unit test" the HTML on a website.

Answer (score 1):

To test, and to better organise your code, you should separate the "action" code from the "rendering" code. This makes each unit of action easily testable:

```
static List<String> extractNameParts(String name) {
    return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(first.split("[ -]")));
}

static String removeSpecialChars(String str) {
    return  str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", "");
}
```

These are obviously easy to test, because they only do one thing.

Note how the name of the method is basically a variant of the comment in your code. As a rule of thumb, instead of writing a comment, create a method instead. Doing this formally names the code, makes it reusable and testable. Your code will look neater and more readable too.

Here's what it might look like:

```
firstNameParts = extractNameParts(first);
System.out.println("Length of First Name Parts: " + firstNameParts.size());

for (int i = 0; i < firstNameParts.size(); i++) {
    String namePart = firstNameParts.get(i);
    System.out.println("First Name Part " + i + ":" + );
    firstNameParts.set(i, removeSpecialChars(namePart);
    System.out.println("Stripped First Name Part " + i + ":" + namePart);
}
```

As for testing the output, you could have your code print to a specified `PrintStream` (of which `System.out` is one) instead of assuming the code prints to the console. You could then have your test code pass a `PrintStream` to the code then examine its contents.